# Is there a way to predict the next execution time for a crontab job?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, crontab

I'm configuring `crontab` jobs on an Ubuntu server and I'm trying to figure out how can I predict the next execution time for my jobs individually. It's just a matter of making sure I configured the pattern properly specially when it comes to complex patterns. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. There is no such thing as predicting the next execution time, as it's deterministically scheduled, and this can be read in the configuration file. Could you give an example of what you are trying to know?

Comment: @m4573r is right, you can't "predict" when a cronjob is going to run, because it only runs exactly when you tell it to. You could send the out of the command to a log file by adding `> /path/to/logfile` to the end of the cronjob.

Comment: @m4573r @bobmagoo, I'm using a java library called `cron4j` which offers the mechanism of predicting the next execution time for a pattern. I was wondering if a similar command exists on linux systems. Check this link: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php#p13

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any simple command line to do that. However you should give [cron_event_predict](http://search.cpan.org/~kohts/Schedule-Cron-Events-1.9/cron_event_predict.plx) a try, it seems to do exactly what you want.